# BOM (bill of material) proper representation in a class

Tags: class, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I need an expert advice on how to represent `BOM` concept in a class. So far in my application I had only one `Equipment`. But now there is a CR for `BOM`integration. So i have to modify my existing `Equipment` class. 
 How can I represent `BOM` child and parent relationship in proper way?

I have one suggestion.

```
class Equipment {

        List <Equipment> childEquipmentList;

        public void addChildEquipment(EREquipmentVO childObject) {
            if(null == childEquipmentList) childEquipmentList = new ArrayList<EREquipmentVO>();
            this.childEquipmentList.add(childObject);
        } 

        public List<EREquipmentVO> getChildEquipmentList() {
              return childEquipmentList;
        }

}
```

Want to know is there any other better way to implement `BOM` relationship in `Equipment` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Each element should be able to calculate total cost of its children. Is that what you want?